# Transit Visa in Suvarnabhumi airport in Thailand

Tags: visas, bangkok

I am travelling from Kunming to Bangalore via Bangkok - swarnabhumi airport.  My itinerary is as below
14 JAN 20
23:00
15 JAN 20
00:45
Kunming Bangkok MU2583 40* 40* MU MTQP5F
2h 45m | Kunming, KMG - Suvarnabhumi International, BKK
LAYOVER 3h 40m
15 JAN 20
04:25
15 JAN 20
06:55
Bangkok Bangalore 6E76 1* INDIGO NMEM4K
4h 0m | Suvarnabhumi International, BKK - Kempegowda International Airport, BLR
Do I need a transit visa as my stay in Bangkok air port is only 3hr. 40 minutes.
I am an indian national studying in China.  Please help and guide me.  Thanks